# Php/Mysql While loop: Date format

Tags: php, mysql, date, loops

I am really new to PHP/Mysql. I recently came up with a simple php loop code that I use to "echo" Name, Date, Time of start, Time of end and Link from my "Events" database. It works perfect.

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=events', 'events', 'Pword');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM events');

while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
?>
<?php echo $donnees['event']; ?><br />
<?php echo $donnees['date']; ?><br />
From <?php echo $donnees['starttime']; ?> to <?php echo $donnees['endtime']; ?><br />
<a href="http://<?php echo $donnees['link']; ?>"><?php echo $donnees['link']; ?></a><br />

<?php
}

$reponse->closeCursor();

?>
```

Now, I've been trying to change the date output by seperating the day, month and year in separate values so that I can echo my own translations (01=January) or (01=Janvier).
The Mysql field has to keep "date" deffault format (yyyy-mm-dd) because I need loop to show only upcoming events: event date => current date (assuming it would work).

Any ideas about how to do that ?

Thank you very much

Comment: did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in PHP with the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$day   = date('j', strtotime($donnees['date'])); 
$month = date('n', strtotime($donnees['date'])); 
$year  = date('Y', strtotime($donnees['date']));
```

or in your query with one of the [mysql date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
select  *,  
        DAY(date) as event_day, 
        MONTH(date) as event_month, 
        YEAR(date) as event_year
 from   events
```

and a query for just the future dates?

```
select * from events where date >= NOW()
```